# Can I write an article in a reputable CS journal not with results but conjecture?

Tags: publications, journals, computer-science

I work in industry and some interesting idea has struck me. This is a conjecture which will take a year or two of full time research work to confirm it although it looks very realistic. Unfortunately I cannot apply for post doctorate or a grant due to my work commitments but I would be glad to publish an article if a reputable CS journals would be interested. This may solve very hard practical problem but surprisingly it is difficult to monetize so I cannot do it in industry.

Comment: The only way to see if they are interested is to try. OTOH, it might be a better idea to submit this (as it isn't finished work) to a conference.

Comment: Or write a position paper and submit this to a workshop.

Comment: vague! meta! try writing it up on a blog 1st and getting feedback there, or just asking the question on stackexchange in the form "will this work?"

Comment: [Reposting a comment that got lost in the migration] See also this related question: [What are examples of appropriate journals to publish new mathematical conjectures?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2375/546)

Comment: If we knew we could resolve the conjecture in a year or two, then it probably wouldn't be research.  More likely is that you can't and won't know whether it's possible to resolve the conjecture in a year or two until you try, so you shouldn't assume it can necessarily be proven/refuted in "a year or two of full time research work".

Answer (score 10):

You can certainly publish an article based on a conjecture.  (One famous case is Subhash Khot's 2002 paper introducing the Unique Games Conjecture.)  On the other hand, you need to include some supporting information in the paper.  Why is your conjecture plausible?  Can you supply examples or applications?  What are its implications or connections with related work?  Answering these questions may be much easier than resolving the conjecture, but they can still require some serious work.

You're most likely to be able to publish the conjecture if there's no straightforward way to resolve it.  If it's clear in principle what you should try, and the only issue is that you don't have time to try it, then you're more likely to meet resistance (it may still be possible, depending on the publication venue, but this would probably rule out many of the more prestigious conferences).